# Bind List<Object> to a comboxbox in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a static class named `Building` which contains a `List<Beam> Beams` as its property;

```
public static class Building
{
    public static readonly List<Beam> Beams = new List<Beam>();
}

public class Beam
{
    public string Story;
    public double Elevation;
}
```

I'm trying to `Bind` the Building.Beams to a combobox in XAML so that Elevation and Story properties of each item in Building.Beams list is displayed in different columns in the combobox. I have been able to implement the two columns, I just can't Bind these properties.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuilding"  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="300">
                <TextBlock Width="150"  Text="{Binding Path=Story }"/>
                <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=Elevation}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

var b1 = new Beam { Elevation = 320, Story = "ST1" };
var b2 = new Beam { Elevation = 640, Story = "ST2" };
Building.Beams.Add(b1);
Building.Beams.Add(b2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuilding" Width="100" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Beams}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="300">
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=Story}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=Elevation}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <Button Content="Add item" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Building building = new Building();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        building.Beams = new List<Beam>();

        building.Beams.Add(new Beam 
                           { 
                               Elevation = 320, 
                               Story = "ST1" 
                           });

        this.DataContext = building;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var b1 = new Beam { Elevation = 320, Story = "ST1" };
        var b2 = new Beam { Elevation = 640, Story = "ST2" };

        building.Beams.Add(b1);
        building.Beams.Add(b2);

        cmbBuilding.Items.Refresh();
    }
}

public class Building
{
    public List<Beam> Beams
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Beam
{
    public string Story 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Elevation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**`Some notes`**

- When you use properties in the `Binding`, you need to be *properties* with get and set, not fields.
- Properties, what were added to the `List<T>` will automatically update, you should call `MyComboBox.Items.Refresh()` method, or use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ObservableCollection represents a *dynamic* data collection that `provides notifications` when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: Thank you so much Anatoliy for the time you put into this. I'm always learning from guys like you.

Comment: Just one thing, my Building class is static. So it wouldn't let me to assign it as a DataContext. So I had to do this: `DataContext = Building.Beams` Is there a better way?

Comment: @Vahid: Why do you use *static* here? Binding usually not used static classes, I advise to do as my example. For `Binding` in static class, implementing pattern [`Singleton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

Comment: I've heard that `Singleton` pattern must be used in very rare situations. Actually I have built my whole program around this static Building class so I have to stick to it.

Comment: `I've heard that Singleton pattern must be used in very rare situations.` - I think this is your case. Or are you doing in my example, or to implement a `Singleton` pattern. You can create a new question about this problem, if you want.

Comment: For now I did like this `combobox.DataContext = Building.Beams`. Thanks.

Comment: @Anatoliy - `Binding usually not used static classes` - That's not true. `x:Static` can be used for that purpose.

Comment: @Rohit Vats: I know about using `x:Static`, you misunderstood my point. I had mind that usually class, which is used as DataContext, is not static. For these purposes it is better to use the pattern Singleton.

Comment: Hmmm or may be class with static properties will do as well. Since post WPF 4.0, we have in place static property change mechanism so having static properties within class will do as well. Personally i avoid Singleton's.

Comment: @Rohit Vats: Yes it is true, or just make a class not static. Singleton is useful when you know when to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **you can't bind with fields**.

Convert Story and Elevation to properties *(automatic properties in your case will do)*

```
public class Beam
{
    public string Story { get; set;}
    public double Elevation { get; set;}
}
```

Second, you should use `ObservableCollection` in case you are adding items to the list after loading finishes so that UI gets notification.

```
public static readonly ObservableCollection<Beam> Beams
                                   = new ObservableCollection<Beam>();
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I've been working on this for nearly 3 hours now!

Answer (score 1):

Is it maybe because you have declared Beams as readonly yet you try to ADD items to it? Beams is also defined as a variable, try removing the readonly and making it a property with a getter and setter

Comment: Yes, it was because of the fields I had used instead of the properties. Thanks